# String split using a delimiter on pandas column to create new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column like this

```
Col1
1 A, 2 B, 3 C
2 B, 4 C
1 B, 2 C, 4 D
```

I have used the `.str.split(',', expand=True)`, the result is like this

```
0   | 1   | 2
1 A | 2 B | 3 C
2 B | 4 C | None
1 B | 2 C | 4 D
```

what I am trying to achieve is to get this one:

```
Col A| Col B| Col C| Col D
1 A  | 2 B  | 3 C  | None
None | 2 B  | 4 C  | None
None | 1 B  | 2 C  | 4 D
```

I am stuck, how to get new columns formatted as such ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try:

```
# split and explode
s = df['Col1'].str.split(', ').explode()

# create new multi-level index
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.index, s.str.split().str[-1].tolist()])

# unstack to reshape
out = s.unstack().add_prefix('Col ')
```

**Details:**

```
# split and explode
0    1 A
0    2 B
0    3 C
1    2 B
1    4 C
2    1 B
2    2 C
2    4 D
Name: Col1, dtype: object

# create new multi-level index
0  A    1 A
   B    2 B
   C    3 C
1  B    2 B
   C    4 C
2  B    1 B
   C    2 C
   D    4 D
Name: Col1, dtype: object

# unstack to reshape
  Col A Col B Col C Col D
0   1 A   2 B   3 C   NaN
1   NaN   2 B   4 C   NaN
2   NaN   1 B   2 C   4 D
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably there are more general approaches you can use but this worked for me. Please note that this is based on a lot of assumptions and constraints of your particular example.

```
test_dict = {'col_1': ['1 A, 2 B, 3 C', '2 B, 4 C', '1 B, 2 C, 4 D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict)
```

First, we split the df into initial columns:

```
df2 = df.col_1.str.split(pat=',', expand=True)
```

Result:

```
    0   1   2
0   1 A 2 B 3 C
1   2 B 4 C None
2   1 B 2 C 4 D
```

Next, (first assumption) we need to ensure that we can later use `' '` as delimiter to extract the columns. In order to do that we need to remove all the starting and trailing spaces from each string

```
func = lambda x: pd.Series([i.strip() for i in x])
df2 = df2.astype(str).apply(func, axis=1)
```

Next, We would need to get a list of unique columns. To do that we first extract column names from each cell:

```
func = lambda x: pd.Series([i.split(' ')[1] for i in x if i != 'None'])
df3 = df2.astype(str).apply(func, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
    0   1   2
0   A   B   C
1   B   C   NaN
2   B   C   D
```

Then create a list of unique columns `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` that are present in your DataFrame:

```
columns_list = pd.unique(df3[df3.columns].values.ravel('K'))
columns_list = [x for x in columns_list if not pd.isna(x)]
```

And create an empty base dataframe with those columns which will be used to assign the corresponding values:
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_list)
Once the preparations are done we can assign column values for each of the rows and use `pd.concat` to merge them back in to one DataFrame:

```
result_list = []
result_list.append(result_df)  # Adding the empty base table to ensure the columns are present
for row in df2.iterrows():
    result_object = {}  # dict that will be used to represent each row in source DataFrame
    for column in columns_list:
        for value in row[1]:  # row is returned in the format of tuple where first value is row_index that we don't need
            if value != 'None':
                if value.split(' ')[1] == column:  # Checking for a correct column to assign
                    result_object[column] = [value]
    result_list.append(pd.DataFrame(result_object))  # Adding dicts per row
```

Once the list of DataFrames is generated we can use `pd.concat` to put it together:

```
final_df = pd.concat(result_list, ignore_index=True)  # ignore_index will rebuild the index for the final_df
```

And the result will be:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1 A 2 B 3 C NaN
1   NaN 2 B 4 C NaN
2   NaN 1 B 2 C 4 D
```

I don't think this is the most elegant and efficient way to do it but it will produce the results you need

Comment: nice solution, though it is not advisable to prefer looping solution over vectorized one, huge performance differences

Comment: Absolutely agree - using native pandas methods is always better than built around loops. Voted up the Shubham Sharma's solution for this answer.